# Cloud Converter app not showing up in Salesforce org

Tags: appexchange, app

We use Cloud Converter app downloaded from the Salesforce appexchange. And since few days, the app isn't 'showing up' or not displaying in production or sandbox orgs (See screenshot)

Did anyone face similar issue with Cloud Converter or any other app? Any ideas why it's happening and how to get it back?

Thanks,
Prabhat

[image: Cloud Converter Error Screenshot]

Comment: I can confirm I'm seeing the same thing.

Comment: I am also having this issue. I got an error stating that the certificate expired, but the app is still available on app exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Converter is just a web tab that points to https://cloudconverter.modelmetrics.com/mmimport/home.action?s={!$Api.Session_ID}&u={!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_150}. It looks like the SSL certificate on that site expired on Friday. This prevents the tab from loading.

Model Metrics is now owned by Salesforce, and I'm not sure anyone is maintaing the model metrics site to get a new certificate. I can't find the app listed on App Exchange either, so I'm not sure how you can get support.

One alternative is [Schema Surfer](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wZM3EAM) to get schema info, but you can't export it to Excel. Another option is [SoqlXplorer](http://www.pocketsoap.com/osx/soqlx/)

UPDATE: It looks like the SSL certificate is now current.
UPDATE 6/8/16:  And down again...

Comment: Interesting...
Here's the fun thing, the app is back up again. I will have to watch and see if this is a recurring thing or it's fixed for good.

Anyways, thanks a lot Daniel!

Comment: Wow, that was fast! The certificate is now current. I'd like to think I was responsible for it. I sent out a tweet and got a response that Salesforce's network engineering had been alerted.

Comment: haha...I happened to tweet it out too!

Comment: It's still not showing up in my sandbox on cs16 and production on na15. Does anyone have a suggestion? I would be very grateful!

Comment: It works for me on NA8. Try just opening a new tab and going to https://cloudconverter.modelmetrics.com/mmimport/home.action. That should tell you if the server is up and responding to your requests. It won't let you view your metadata, though.